# The name frm does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, winforms

The name frm does not exist in the current context.

```
public partial class frmProduct : Form
{

    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
    DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    frmProductList flist;

    public frmProduct(frmProductList flist)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cn = new SqlConnection(dbcon.MyConnection());
      flist = frm; //Error on this line "frm"
    }
```

Comment: That's because `frm` does not exist in the current context, as the error tells you. Just read your own code. Where is `frm`? Nowhere.

Comment: You forgot all the important bits, like what name, what line, the actual exception message, and basically everything which would make this a good question. please read [ask]

Comment: public partial class frmBrand : Form
    {

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
        DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection();
        Company frmlist;
        public frmBrand(Company flist)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cn = new SqlConnection(dbcon.MyConnection());
            frmlist = flist;
        }  // Look at this Code this work on my other WInform but the one above is not working

Answer (score 0):

public partial class frmProduct : Form
{

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection();
SqlDataReader dr;
frmProductList flist;

public frmProduct(frmProductList frm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cn = new SqlConnection(dbcon.MyConnection());
  flist = frm; 
}
```

//FInally Resolved it my Self, Thanks for the help